Casting string column to pl.DateTime does not keep timezone information while converting to string does
Polars version 1.17.11
I have a json object with the following structure:
json_obj = [
    {"timestamp": "2024-10-01T21:23:23Z", "value": 31},
    {"timestamp": "2024-10-01T23:44:11.124Z", "value": -453.2}
]

and I want to create a DataFrame in which the first column has the pl.Datetime data type including the timezone and the second column is a pl.Float64. But creating the DataFrame with the schema {"timestamp": pl.Datetime, "value": pl.Float64} gives me a ComputeError and if I create the DataFrame without the schema, then cast the timestamp column to pl.Datetime I lose the timezone information.
When I create the DataFrame:
json_obj = [
    {"timestamp": "2024-10-01T21:23:23Z", "value": 31},
    {"timestamp": "2024-10-01T23:44:11.124Z", "value": -453.2}
]
df = pl.DataFrame(json_obj)
print(df)

It outputs to:
shape: (2, 2)
┌──────────────────────────┬────────┐
│ timestamp                ┆ value  │
│ ---                      ┆ ---    │
│ str                      ┆ f64    │
╞══════════════════════════╪════════╡
│ 2024-10-01T21:23:23Z     ┆ 31.0   │
│ 2024-10-01T23:44:11.124Z ┆ -453.2 │
└──────────────────────────┴────────┘

Note that the second column casts automatically to f64 despite the first value being an integer, which is good. But I want to change the type of the first column to timezone-aware datetime:
df = df.cast({"timestamp": pl.Datetime})
print(df)

Which outputs to:
shape: (2, 2)
┌─────────────────────────┬────────┐
│ timestamp               ┆ value  │
│ ---                     ┆ ---    │
│ datetime[μs]            ┆ f64    │
╞═════════════════════════╪════════╡
│ 2024-10-01 21:23:23     ┆ 31.0   │
│ 2024-10-01 23:44:11.124 ┆ -453.2 │
└─────────────────────────┴────────┘

The first column is casted to datetime[µs] but it removed the timezone information.
However, if I recreate the same dataframe but this time replace the timestamp column with a string operation:
json_obj = [
    {"timestamp": "2024-10-01T21:23:23Z", "value": 31},
    {"timestamp": "2024-10-01T23:44:11.124Z", "value": -453.2}
]
df = pl.DataFrame(json_obj)
df = df.with_columns(pl.col("timestamp").str.to_datetime())
print(df)

I obtain the following result:
shape: (2, 2)
┌─────────────────────────────┬────────┐
│ timestamp                   ┆ value  │
│ ---                         ┆ ---    │
│ datetime[μs, UTC]           ┆ f64    │
╞═════════════════════════════╪════════╡
│ 2024-10-01 21:23:23 UTC     ┆ 31.0   │
│ 2024-10-01 23:44:11.124 UTC ┆ -453.2 │
└─────────────────────────────┴────────┘

Now I have the timestamp as type datetime[µs, UTC] without the timezone information lost.
Could someone explain why the casting behaves differently?

What part of the man page did you find confusing? I don't see you modeling a timezone for the column anywhere. I only see you distinguishing between naive and aware objects. // Standard python advice: avoid naive datetimes if you can. Standard RDBMS and computing advice: store just UTC timestamps on disk, and worry about zone offsets on the way in and the way out as part of the UI presentation layer.

I think the f64 cast may be considered a "bug". pl.DataFrame({"x": [1, 2.0]}) raises an error, but the "nested list" invocation seems to bypass the strict=True default. pl.DataFrame([{"x": 1}, {"x": 2.0}]) - Similarly, I would have guessed that .cast(pl.Datetime) and .str.to_datetime() would be equivalent. I'm not sure if this would also be considered as a "bug"? Perhaps it needs to be raised on Github.
